# A matrix is an orthogonal projection if idempotent and symmetric.

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

I have a matrix $A=\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^t$ where **v** is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with magnitude $1$. 
I have to prove that $A$ represents an orthogonal projection onto span$\{\mathbf{v}\}$.

I have shown that $A$ is symmetric and idempotent with rank $1$ but I am not sure how to go from those properties to it being an orthogonal projection.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: related question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163353/projection-onto-subspaces-point-to-line-projection/1163446#1163446

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the body of your question is much quicker than the answer to the title.

Note that for any vector $x$, we have
$$
Ax = vv^Tx = v\langle x,v \rangle = \langle x,v \rangle v
$$
By definition, this is the projection of $x$ onto the vector $v$.

Yes, we could prove that in general, a matrix is an orthogonal projection if it is idempotent and symmetric.  However, doing so is not necessary in answering this particular question.

Comment: Why does the equality $vv^T x= (v^Tx)v$ hold?

Comment: @Thorsten $v^T x$ is a real number.

Comment: Made it clearer